# Magento - Using getPriceHtml on custom product collection doesn't return correct tax price

Tags: magento

I have a product collection called using the following (set to show 6 items):

```
$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->setPageSize(6);
$_testproductCollection->load();
```

then i get the 6 products details with a foreach:

```
foreach($_testproductCollection as $_testproduct){ 
    echo "Price is ".$this->htmlEscape($this->getPriceHtml($_product, true))."<br/>"; 
};
```

this works ok until I set my store to show prices inclusive of tax. Instead of showing 2 different prices, for example:

```
Excl. Tax: $138.56 
Incl. Tax: $149.99
```

it shows the same price for both. If I add a call to the loaded product collection again immediately after it's loaded:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

...it works fine, the prices are correct, but then it's skipping the **setPageSize** function and returning the full store collection of products.

How can I get the correct tax prices to show, and what is it in the **getLoadedProductCollection** that corrects this? The function is in Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection::addTaxPercents`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection.html#addTaxPercents)

Also, the `getLoadedProductCollection` calls (via a catalog layer) the [`addMinimalPrice`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection.html#addMinimalPrice) and [`addFinalPrice`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection.html#addFinalPrice) methods. From those docs you can see there are methods for adding tiered pricing and URL rewrites. That is nice to know.

Comment: Sweet, figured it out - adding an **->addFinalPrice()** to my collection call fixes the issue, cheers!